# Issue with Casting string to date in Teradata

Tags: teradata, informatica-powercenter

I have a string column - COL1 in TABLE1 which is if string data type. This table is loaded by Informatica session ( data coming from mainframe) and the format of the COL1 is YYYY-MM-DD. Now I have to use TABLE1 as the source in my next mapping . In the SQL override query of second mapping i will be casting COL1 to date using the below query .

```
SELECT
CAST(COL1 AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS CHK_DT FROM TABLE1
```

But when i try to execute this query in Teradata SQLA, just to check if it runs fine it gives me below error.

```
SELECT Failed. 2666:  Invalid date supplied for COL1.
```

Can you please help me resolve this issue ? This is not the only date column which has issue, there are two more date columns . I guess the resolution is same for all three columns .

P.S - Just to verify, I updated all rows of COL1 of TABLE1 as 2016-12-12 and ran the select statement, select worked fine . I then updated COL1 of all rows as 2016-13-12, it gave same error . If either of DD or MM is more than 12, it is giving me error

Thanks

Comment: What date do you expect for `2016-13-12` in `yyyy-mm-dd` format?

Answer (score 1):

If `DATE` is represented/stored in ANSI standard literal `YYYY-MM-DD`, the `CAST` will work.

```
SELECT CAST('2016-12-13' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS Date1
```

[image]

However i doubt that in your case.

The date is most probably in `YYYY-DD-MM` format. In that case the ANSI standard format will throw the error. You need `YYYY-DD-MM`

```
select  CAST('2016-13-12' AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-DD-MM') AS Date2
```

[image]

*P.S. You can confirm the conversion to date using `TYPE()` function. It should return `DATE` in your case*

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try this piece of code

```
CAST(CAST(date_col AS FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS VARCHAR(15))
```

instead of the transformation you are using.

Comment: But the output of my cast should be date . In the above case it is again converted to char .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.  However the issue was something else.  Some of the incoming records had space in this column . So I had to tweak my informatica mapping to put a trim on date column . Now the select is running fine . Thanks for your time .